# powershell query - how many OR can i use?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I can not find any informations about -Filter limitations in powershell
I would like to query many groups on exchange server using

```
Get-DistributionGroup
```

But count of these groups will be large, and i would divide this query into many queries, (like every 50 if that is the limitation of using -OR parameter in filter)

In the end the command will be like :

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter "(Name like xyz) -or (Name like 'abc') or (Name like 'def')"
```

Somebody knows that is there any limitations using -or on filter?

Or maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested, there are limits of 250 subfilters. I have set logging on  server when command sended to exchange server will not be successfull,
and got info :

```
   Call Site: SomeProject.PowerShell.Service.PowershellCommand`1.Execute
   Exception Type: 
   Exception Message: 
   Stack Trace: 
   Additional Info: Could not invoke command Get-Group, Details:
 The total number of explicit and implicit subfilters exceeds maximum allowed number of 250.  Processing stopped.
```

**The content after "Details:" is message from remote exchange server**

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1) Build filter programmatically**

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps) doesn't mention a limit. It would be easier to create the filter automatically though, and retrieve the search terms from a file or variable:

```bsh
# get the search values from a file or variable
$searchTerms = Get-Content "searchTerms.txt"
# OR define the values in your script
$searchTerms = "xyz", "abc", "def"

# build the filter
$filter = ($searchTerms | foreach {"(Name like '$_')"}) -join " -or "
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter $filter
```

**Option 2) Filter by each search term separately**

Splitting up the filter would also be possible, but you would have to remove duplicates, like this:

```
$searchTerms | foreach {Get-DistributionGroup -Filter "(Name like '$_')"} | select -Unique
```

**Option 3) Fallback: Query all and do your own filtering**

Alternatively, you could get all distribution groups and do your own filtering:

```bsh
Get-DistributionGroup | where {
    $name = $_.Name
    return $null -ne $searchTerms.where({$name -like $_}, "First")
}
```

Comment: i would prefer not to get all the groups (we have 10k+)

Comment: thanks, but i belive if i use where with pipe it will firstly get all groups from exchange and then enumeare them into memory

Comment: 2nd option is actually this same
and the first is just like brute force ;)

Comment: man, my question was how many -OR can i use in query, i still don't know, and built query like in 1st option is nothing hard, i can simple use foreach - i didn't ask for this.

the second and the third are both download all data from server

Comment: @pawelek91 If you want our help, please be more cooperative. I answered your question already: The documentation says *no limit*. Why do you ask that, did you have any errors? Your question mentions nothing. Also, I as I already said, the 2nd option **does not** download all data from server. If you don't understand the code, you should ask, not criticize it.

Comment: yeah im sorry, was tired, 2nd command doesn't get all data from server, but it's still nothing what i asked for.
still the documentation does not say anything about limits, it does not mean that there are not any limits